# String into array with key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, string, serialization

I have serialized filed

```
"date_from=&time_from=&date_to=&time_to=&email=&title=&text=&date_from_full=&date_to_full=&sortID=SortiddReverse&"
```

what i need to convert into array with key value pair ive tried .explode , but it didnt worked as i needed

```
 0 => "date_from="
  1 => "time_from="
  2 => "date_to="
  3 => "time_to="
  4 => "email=1"
  5 => "title=1111"
  6 => "text=1111"
  7 => "date_from_full="
  8 => "date_to_full="
  9 => "sortID=SortiddReverse"
  10 => ""
```

how can i fix that?

Comment: So what have you tried?  Where is your source code?

Comment: You are asking for key/value pairs, but list a numbered array as expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already function in PHP for that named [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to retrieve the key/value pairs you asked for.

```
$string = "date_from=&time_from=&date_to=&time_to=&email=&title=&text=&date_from_full=&date_to_full=&sortID=SortiddReverse&";

$array = [];
parse_str($string, $array):
```

and will output

```
array(10) {
  'date_from' =>
  string(0) ""
  'time_from' =>
  string(0) ""
  'date_to' =>
  string(0) ""
  'time_to' =>
  string(0) ""
  'email' =>
  string(0) ""
  'title' =>
  string(0) ""
  'text' =>
  string(0) ""
  'date_from_full' =>
  string(0) ""
  'date_to_full' =>
  string(0) ""
  'sortID' =>
  string(14) "SortiddReverse"
}
```